# VUEJS - Why do I get: Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof'?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am facing issue in vue.js about "Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object".

I am using Vue 2.2.1 version following is my code snippet where I am getting this issue.

```
Vue.component('componentName', {
'template': ``,
 props: {
  contentTypeUid: {
    type: 'string',
    required: false
  },
  limit: {
    type: 'number',
    required: false,
    default: 10
  }
 },
 ......
});
```

While if instead of above following working without any issue, but I want to use above format as I need to specify some validations and default values on props.

```
Vue.component('componentName', {
'template': ``,
 props: ["contentTypeUid", "limit"],
 ......
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use:

```
props: {
  contentTypeUid: {
    type: String, // not 'string'
    required: false
  },
  limit: {
    type: Number, // not 'number'
    required: false,
    default: 10
  }
 },
```

Comment: Another case where this can occur is using `type: {}` instead of `type: Object`

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was a component property that had a null type:

```
props: {
    role:{
      type: [String, null],
      required: true
    },
```

changing it to

```
props: {
   role:{
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
```

And making sure, that the component always gets a string, fixed the issue.
I guess the combination of required and a possible null value was not very good...

Comment: You could also use `String | null` in this case

Answer (score 3):

Another case why this error might occur:

```
props: {
    prop_id: {
        required: true
    },
    title: 'Not specified'
},
```

So you need to change it to:

```
props: {
    prop_id: {
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        default: 'Not specified'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

My case:

```
    props: {
        userId: {
            type: String | Number,
        }
    },
```

changing to

```
  props: {
    userId: {
        type: [String, Number],
    }
},
```

helped